# Wait for button press JButton

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, actionlistener, jlabel

I am looking for a way of making my program wait until a button is pressed to continue the function. In my main function i am calling a function which shows my basic GUI using JPanel, buttons and labels. ofcourse, it shows the GUI and ends that function not allowing me to alter the GUI.

```
    public static Player player = new Player();
    public static Gui gui = new Gui();
    public static boolean inMain = true;
    public static boolean inBattle = false;

    public static void main(String[] args){
    showMainGui();  
    }
```

I think what im looking for is something that will look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    showMainGui();
    while(inBattle == false){
        // wait until inBattle changes
    }
}
```

That while loop will loop and wait until a button created in showMainGui changes inBattle to true. How could i do this exactly? This is rather confusing me. My goal is to click a JButton and the buttons change to different buttons

My action listener for my button created on the showMainGui();

```
public class Hunt implements ActionListener{

    @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    MainClass.inBattle = true;
}
}
```

and here is my showMainGui() method

```
public static void showMainGui(){
    gui.panel.add(gui.healthLabel);
    gui.panel.add(gui.pbsLabel);
    gui.panel.add(gui.staminaLabel);
    gui.panel.add(gui.levelLabel);

    //Adding initial buttons
    gui.panel.add(gui.exploreButton);
    gui.panel.add(gui.huntButton);
    gui.panel.add(gui.newsLabel);
    gui.panel.add(gui.effectLabel);
    updateGui();

}
```

Comment: can you provide some more code? where you change inBattel and how + showMainGUI method

Comment: Sorry, showMainGUI gives us no information. Perhaps updateGUI can...

Comment: All updateGui does is sets the Labels text to the variables

Comment: so what is calling setVisible method? new Gui()?

Comment: Yeah, setVisible is in the gui instance

Comment: So there are many things to learn for you :). I would recommend something like this http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/

Comment: It appears I do! Thank you very much, I will use the website provided :)

Comment: @Darryl : Why not simply pop a [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html), that will block the flow, until you get some sort of an input from the user to proceed with ? For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9107536/1057230)

Answer (score 8):

You can wait by putting thread to sleep.

```
while(inBattle == false){
    try {
       Thread.sleep(200);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
// perform operations when inBattle is true
```

Also don't forget to make inBattle [volatile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html)

Comment: I had tried the sleep method, didnt appear to work for me but i will try it exactly as your have it. Could you please explain volatile? I have not yet learnt that

Comment: Your GUI is being executed on another thread, Main thread should wait otherwise it will finish executing and terminate. this inbattle variable is a shared variable by which you're making your synchronization

Comment: Thanks, I understand that now, but how can I make the variable volatile?

Comment: just add volatile into declaration `public static volatile boolean inBattle = false;`

Comment: I have done that but appears no change. If i was to add my buttons from the main method, rather than calling a function which adds the items to the instance, Would that work?

Comment: you are not suggesting to sleep on the EDT, are you?

Comment: I only showed how to make thread sleep, there is so much to learn that I already suggested a tutorial to the author.

Answer (score 5):

I would +1 [Peters answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17989811/2634190), but I feel this needs some elaboration.

There's absolutely **no need for a while loop or additional threading**. Simply add listeners to your UI components. Here's a very simple example:

```
    JButton button = new JButton("This is a button!");

    //Add action listener to button
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Perform function when button is pressed
        System.out.println("You clicked the button");
    }
 });
```

---

You have added the action listener while still keeping the while loop, why? REMOVE the while loop and use the listener.

Repeating [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17989811/2634190) again, but [RTFM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html). Just [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html), which provides clear examples. There's no good reason to use that loop.

---

Your application is not crashing, it's doing exactly what you're telling it to do:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    showMainGui();
    while(inBattle == false){
        // wait until inBattle changes
    }
}
```

You're saying, WHILE inBattle is false, do nothing, but if inBattle is true, do nothing then end the main function -- What do you expect it to do after you click the button if there's nothing to be done?

Comment: I already have a button with an action listener created in my showMainGui() function. When I use my button, it crashes the application

Answer (score 1):

add a listeners to your button and change in the listener

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The above answers did not answer my version of the question, so I tinkered around with another solution. When I searched up "wait for button press jbutton", this was the first answer.

My solution, which worked, uses the concept of wait-notify. I attached an ActionListener to the Button:

```java
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
             buttonClicked = true;
             synchronized (b) {
                 b.notify();
                 
             } 
    }
```

(Sorry for the indents, if anyone wants to edit, go ahead) This sends a notify when the button is clicked. Then I attached a method called waitForEnter():

```java
public static void waitForEnter() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(b) {
            try {
                
                b.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After button clicked");
    //... more code
    }
```

When I called this method, it would pause the execution of the main Thread until the button named "b" is clicked. This worked very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a solution to this when reading this answer, but I realized that this might help you if you're trying to help update your gui.

I'm assuming that you're using JPanels and stuff (I am), but you should try this:

In my game:

```
MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
    WelcomePanel welcome = new WelcomePanel(window);
    window.add(welcome);
    window.setVisible(true);

    while (Data.isWelcomeConfigDone != true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}

    }
    window.validate();
    window.setVisible(false);
    window.remove(welcome);

    GamePanel game = new GamePanel(window, welcome);

    window.add(game);
    window.setVisible(true);
    game.setVisible(true);

    while (true) {}
```

I had the same idea as you, just make a loop until my condition becomes false. However, I get the feeling that the guy isn't updating, so you need to add this:

```
window.validate(); // or whatever it is. My window is a JFrame, 
                      but it should work in a JPanel
```

I know this is really late, but for whoever pops up in this question, this should hopefully help.

`validate()` doc:

> public void validate()
>   Validates this container and all of its subcomponents.
>   The validate method is used to cause a container to lay out its subcomponents again. It should be invoked when this container's subcomponents are modified (added to or removed from the container, or layout-related information changed) after the container has been displayed.
>
> If this Container is not valid, this method invokes the validateTree method and marks this Container as valid. Otherwise, no action is performed.
>
> Overrides:
>   validate in class Component
>   See Also:
>   add(java.awt.Component), Component.invalidate(), JComponent.revalidate(), validateTree()